# Problem with "Hovering" state in ardrome/navdata topic

Tags: ros, ardrone2.0

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Problem with "Hovering" state in ardrome/navdata topic

I'm trying to implement a .cpp program to take a picture when my AR.Drone 2 goes to a position that I ask it to go and take a picture when it stabilises in hovering state. I used **ardrome_autonomy** and **tum_ardrone** to navigate the drone. In my takepicture.cpp program I used a subscriber to the navdata topic. Everything works fine except from the fact like when the drone moves from on position to an other the status that the navdata topic sends is always *"flying"*. Even when it reaches the goto target that I have set, it never enters the *"Hovering"* state. The other states work fine (*like the landing,looping,etc*).

---

Any ideas on what might be going wrong? Or how to know that the drone is hovering without using navdata.state ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204507/problem-with-%22hovering%22-state-in-ardrome/navdata-topic/) by [Michael Panayiotou](https://answers.ros.org/users/18803/michael-panayiotou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi in "hovering" state,can your ardrone hold posititon?  Even i used a oriental tag on the ground,the drone drifting too.

---

Originally posted by [NickShen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25381/nickshen/) with karma: 16 on 2015-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0